# How do I return a list of Grandparents and their Grandchildren from a table of Parents and Children using SQL?

Tags: sql

There is a table with 2 columns, Parent and Child.  Some of the children are also listed in the Parent column.  How do I return a list of grandparents and their children?

```
Parent   |   Child
Tom      |   Joe 
Sam      |   Mark
Mark     |   Gil
Joe      |   Sal
Joe      |   Dan
```

Wanted result:

```
Grandparent|   Grandchild
Sam        |   Gil
Tom        |   Sal
Tom        |   Dan
```

I found how to get the grandparents.

```
SELECT Parent as Grandparent
FROM ParentChild
WHERE Child IN (Select Parent from ParentChild)
```

But I assume I need to use a join to make this work properly, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Note that the answers below give you what you need now, but you might want to look into [recursive CTEs](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/), in case you need to identify N-level relationships (great-grandchildren, great-great-grandchildren, etc.) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-join:

```
select tp.parent, tgc.child
from t tp join
     t tgc
     on tp.child = tgc.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GrandData.Parent as Grandparent, ParentData.GrandChild as Grandchild

From ParentChild as GrandData

Inner JOIN 
(
    SELECT Parent as Parent, Child as GrandChild
    FROM ParentChild
    WHERE Parent IN (Select Child from ParentChild)
) As ParentData

On GrandData.Child=ParentData.Parent

Order by GrandData.Parent
```

You have to identify the parent child relation first as in the inner query and then later you can do inner join based on parent child relation for next generation(grandparent).